# optimal solution for lookup on large sql server table

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, hashtable

I have a large table of user ids and another table of user records which contains a user post with user ids. The process is whenever a new feed post is retrieved,I do a request to the user id table for an id that is marked inactive ( I have that field ACTIVE because I have another process that creates these ids and inserts it continuously into table 1) and when an id is requested it is marked as inactive.
Then I check if the user exists in the user table(table 2) and if so return the user id associated with that user.

I was told that I can speed up this process but creating a hash table to do the lookup on table 2. I am not sure how to even start this and any links or samples will be appreciated.
Also I need to run a separate process that cleans table 1 and removes all inactive user ids.

When I call the procedure to insert into table 2, I pass the user id retrieved from table 1.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[userforums]
  (
     [userid]       [VARCHAR](16) NOT NULL  CONSTRAINT [PK_forumssiteid] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ,
     [forumname]    [VARCHAR](500) NOT NULL,
     [exported]     [INT] NULL,
     [lastcrawled]  [DATETIME] NULL,
     [priority]     [INT] NULL,
     [origin]       [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
     [queryid]      [VARCHAR](25) NULL,
     [dateinserted] [DATETIME] NULL DEFAULT (getdate()) 
   )
```

second table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[userids]
  (
     [userid] [NVARCHAR](20) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [PK_userids] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
     [active] [NVARCHAR](20) NULL  CONSTRAINT [IX_userids] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
  )
```

get user id stored procedure

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

SELECT TOP 1 @id = userid
FROM   userids WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
WHERE  active = 'Y'
        OR active IS NULL

UPDATE userids
SET    active = 'N'
WHERE  userid = @id

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

check if userid exists

```
CREATE PROC Foo @forumname VARCHAR(500),
                @userid    VARCHAR(16),
                @origin    VARCHAR(50),
                @queryid   VARCHAR(25)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @cnt INT
    DECLARE @serverip VARCHAR(16)
    DECLARE @mincnt INT
    DECLARE @siteservercnt INT

    SELECT @cnt = COUNT(*)
    FROM   userforums
    WHERE  forumname = @forumname

    IF @cnt = 0
      BEGIN
          INSERT INTO userforums
                      (forumname,
                       userid,
                       exported,
                       origin,
                       queryid)
          VALUES     (@forumname,
                      @userid,
                      1,
                      @origin,
                      @queryid)

          SELECT @siteservercnt = COUNT(*)
          FROM   siteserverip
          WHERE  userid = @userid

          IF @siteservercnt = 0
            BEGIN
                SELECT TOP 1 @mincnt = COUNT(*),
                             @serverip = serverip
                FROM   siteserverip
                GROUP  BY serverip
                ORDER  BY COUNT(*)

                SELECT TOP 1 @mincnt = sitecount,
                             @serverip = serverip
                FROM   serveripcounts
                ORDER  BY sitecount

                INSERT INTO siteserverip
                VALUES     (@siteid,
                            @serverip)

                UPDATE serveripcounts
                SET    sitecount = sitecount + 1
                WHERE  serverip = @serverip
            END
      END

    SELECT userid
    FROM   userforums
    WHERE  forumname = @forumname

    RETURN
```

Comment: The optimal solution would probably be to create an index. Please supply your `CREATE TABLE` statements and the queries you are running,

Comment: Your description is a lot more ambiguous than you think.  As Martin said, please provide the relevant queries and table definitions.

Comment: You might be interested in [USING TABLES AS QUEUES](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/)

Comment: Also your second proc is doing a lot more than you indicated in the original text. You'll just have to tune the queries and do performance analysis looking at the execution plans and wait stats for any bottle necks.

Comment: thanks for the response. I realize I will have to tune the query but also how does queueing help with the second procedure functionality.

Comment: It doesn't but your statement indicated that the lookup on table 2 was the thing you were trying to optimize. Asking how to optimise a specific query is OK for SO. Asking how to optimise multiple you should hire a consultant IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your existing dequeue query can be improved. Instead of

```
DECLARE @id INT

SELECT TOP 1 @id = userid
FROM   userids WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
WHERE  active = 'Y'
        OR active IS NULL

UPDATE userids
SET    active = 'N'
WHERE  userid = @id
```

Which is two operations (a clustered index scan followed by an index seek) you can do

```
UPDATE TOP (1) userids  
WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST)
SET  active = 'N'
OUTPUT INSERTED.userid
WHERE  active <> 'N'
```

Which is one operation and gives a plan with two range seeks.

Comment: thanks; will your statement update the field before another thread selects the top 1 userid

Comment: @vbNewbie - The read part of the query will take `U` locks. It is not possible for two concurrent transactions to take `U` locks on the same row. You might also want to consider `with (rowlock, readpast)` hints so that any concurrent transaction moves onto the next row rather than being blocked.

Answer (score -1):

A Hash table #TableName is a temporary object in tempdb that functions as a table.  They are generally called 'temp tables'.  I would NOT be using them as a first solution for retrieving data on the fly if this is a common occurrence.  Instead I would create an index and see if that justifies your needs.  Generally hash tables are used for intense operations where you want to get a set of things that may or may not be indexed and then relate it to something else and you want to keep it in memory.

I would create an index and that should improve speed.  Also if you find is slow, a hash table won't speed that part up, it will just be putting a collection of that into a source to reuse seperated from the main table.

```
create index IX_[yourtableName]_[TableColumn(s)] on [Tablename]([Column(s)]
```

I would not create more objects unless necessary.  Generally if your UserId's are valid ints you can search on them quite fast.

Comment: That isn't usually what the term [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) refers to. I don't think I've ever heard anyone refer to `#temp` tables as hash tables before.

Comment: ok now I am confused. Thanks for the responses people. I was told by senior developers here that my processes are running too slow and perhaps a hash table would help with my lookups. When I debug my app it loops through pretty fast, faster than I can hit the continue (F5) key; when tested in a messaging system the rate was about 2 per sec which according to them should be significantly higher

Comment: Generally speaking most admins put their fastest hardware for the tempdb to use.  This improves speed for temp tables.  This makes them faster.  However A LOT of organizations go for temp tables right away to get a 0.00000009 improvement of speed from something that can be done simply with CTE's, table variables, indexes, etc.  If your management wants a temp table, by all means do it.  I would have someone explain to you why they want a temp table so bad though as ultimately you are feeding data into something that way, instead of just selecting it. I would have to know more what they want.

Comment: @Martin:  Really?  Maybe I have been wrong all these years then.  I thought any table with a '#' hash in front of it was stored in the tempdb and known as a 'hashtable' or 'temp table' as it was stored temporarily in the tempdb.  The answer you gave I was always related to as 'bridge' tables.  In that they store data in one place and bridge to another.  I get what you are stating though, interesting.  Well it is bad news then that most people associate hash tables with the '#' I guess then.

Comment: See the wiki article linked in my first comment. SQL Server uses hash tables when doing hash joins for example.

Comment: updated my statement, missed your link before amending my detail.  Thanks I used different terminology for those as 'bridge' tables.  Hash in my mind confuses the person as there is a '#' in front of tables that in my mind justifies that definition.  Guess I had been confused by many people and I learned the wrong thing.  Unlearning it will be something I should try to do I guess.

Comment: #temp tables referred to as 'hash tables' is fairly common (not that that makes it correct of course)  http://www.sqlservercentral.com/search/?q=%22hash+table%22&t=a&t=b&t=f&t=s